# Downloading Azure blob using shared access signature fails with curl or httr

Tags: r, curl, azure-blob-storage, rcurl, httr

I've managed to download from blob storage before using `curl::curl_download` and `httr::GET`, but this time it's failing with a 400 error. However, if I use base R's `download.file`, it works.

The download URL is (copied verbatim, but omitting the file details and actual signature):

```
https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/{store}/{file.zip}?sp=r&st=2018-05-19T00:00:00Z&se=2018-05-31T00:00:00Z&spr=https&sv=2017-07-29&sig={...}&sr=b
```

of which the SAS portion is

```
sp=r&st=2018-05-19T00:00:00Z&se=2018-05-31T00:00:00Z&spr=https&sv=2017-07-29&sig={...}&sr=b
```

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it had nothing to do with the SAS. The filename had a space in it, which the default `download.file` on Windows turns into a `%20`, but curl doesn't. Manually encoding the space as `%20` fixed the problem.